# cannot show ActionBar icon in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am not able to show the Action Bar icon as in the picture below -

[image]

The layout file is -

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment  android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:name="com.nvoids.pradyut.testapp2.MainActivityFragment"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

However with this layout file I m able to view the icon -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The view I m getting is -

[image]

Comment: Try using `Toolbar`. It is more customizable than `ActionBar`.

Comment: I am targeting older versions of Android as well atleast 4.0. Toolbar is with Kitkat i think

Comment: Well in that case you can use android support library for supporting older version, `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`.

Comment: Actionbar icons are in xml located in res -> menu, add your items here

Comment: Are you using any support library?